Using the Vanishing Lie Derivative of a k-form to show it is constant on fibers
This is a follow up to this question. In particular, I want to focus on a specific sub-question.
Given a surjective smooth submersion, $\pi: M \rightarrow N$, a k-form $\omega$ where the Lie Derivative vanishes, $\mathcal{L}_V \omega = 0$, for any vertical vector field $V$, where a vertical vector field is a vector field where $d\pi(V_p) = 0$ and $i_V \omega = 0$
and $i_Vd\omega = 0$.
The answer above suggests that we can show that $\omega_p(v_1, ..., v_n) = \omega_{p'}(u_1, ..., u_n)$ where $p$ and $p'$ are in the same fiber and $d\pi(v_i)_p = d\pi(u_i)_{p'}$ without constructing local coordinates.
Any hints as how we would show this? I thought about using the associated flow $\theta_t$ for a vertical vector field $V$ and the fact that $\theta_t^{*} \omega = \omega_p$, but it seems that one would have to show that $d\pi(d\theta_t(v_i)) = d\pi(v_i)$ which I can't seem to show.

The paragraph presenting your question is very hard to parse (and $v$ should be $V$). Remember that we've already shown that the particular vectors projecting down don’t matter. We just need connected fibers to get a vertical vector field flowing from $p$ to $p’$.

I am with @ted here ... Not sure I understand exactly what (if anything) you assume from the previous answer, and hence precise your question. But two tips (1) what does $d\pi(u_i-v_i)=0$ tell you, and (2) The property $i_v\omega$ is handy ay any slot of $\omega$ by skew-symmetry.

@WishYouTheBest $u_i \in TM_p$ and $v_i \in TM_{p'}$ If they happened to live in the same vector space then it would tell us that their difference is a vertical vector. What I am struggling with is filling in the exact details in a coordinate free way, that the vanishing of the Lie Derivative on vertical vector fields leads to the equivalence within a fiber. Intuitively, it makes sense because the Lie Derivative vanishing should imply that $\omega$ is constant on fibers.

@TedShifrin at a single point, $p$, yes it is obvious from linearity and the fact that vertical vectors annihilate $\omega$ so to speak that it doesn't matter which vectors we choose to evaluate $\omega$ as long they are equivalent under $d\pi$. What I don't understand is your second comment, "We just need connected fibers to get a vertical vector field flowing from
to ′" and I am trying to fill in the details here and maybe I am missing some intuition for what happens when you flow vectors along a vertical vector field. Is the horizontal component preserved and how do we show that?

I just reread your post. All you're missing once you apply what I said is your very last statement. But $\pi\circ\theta_t = \pi$, so what you wrote is precisely the chain rule.

@TedShifrin thanks! The insight that $\pi \circ \ \theta_t = \pi$ seems obvious in hindsight and helps me complete the proof. Feel free to post an answer about that if you'd like me to accept it.

So the set-up from the linked question is that we have a surjective smooth submersion $F\colon M\to N$. We have a $k$-form $\omega$ on $M$ with the property that $\iota_V\omega=0$ and $\mathscr L_V\omega = 0$ for any vertical vector field $V$. If we assume that the fibers of $F$ are connected, it then follows that $\omega = F^*\eta$ for some $k$-form $\eta$ on $N$.
As in the answer in that question, we set $\eta_q(w_1,\dots,w_k) = \omega_p(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ for any $p$ with $F(p)=q$ and $v_j$ with $dF_p(v_j)=w_j$ for all $j$. The condition that $\iota_V\omega=0$ tells us that this definition is independent of the choice of the vectors $v_j$.
Now why does it not depend on the choice of $p\in F^{-1}(q)$? Here we must use the hypothesis that the submanifold $M_q=F^{-1}(q)$ is connected. It is a standard fact from differential topology that we can always find a vector field $V$ on $M_q$ whose time-one flow $\varphi$ carries $p$ to $q$. (See, for example, the homogeneity lemma in $\S$4 of Milnor's Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint. Also, if you feel the need to do so, you can use the local product structure to extend $V$ to get a vertical vector field on a tube around $M_q$ with the same property.) Since $\mathscr L_V\omega = 0$, we conclude that $\varphi^*\omega = \omega$ and so $\omega_p(v_1,\dots,v_k) = \omega_q(d\varphi_p(v_1),\dots,d\varphi_p(v_k))$. But because $F\circ\varphi=F$, if $v_1,\dots,v_k\in T_pM$ project to $w_j$, then so will $d\varphi_p(v_j)\in T_qM$, as $dF_p(v_j) = d(F\circ\varphi)_p(v_j) = dF_q(d\varphi_p(v_j))$.
Thus, we've established the well-definedness of $\eta$.
